# .NET Exception Handling with discrete error codes

Tags: c#, linq

I am writing a method (for a service) that returns a **specific error code** to the client.

Inside this method I am calling various LINQ extension methods. Each one of these extension methods can throw exceptions of 'same' type (say `InvalidOperationException`), but I need to catch these exceptions individually and return a specific error code. Here is what it looks like now (much simplified version)

```
public errorCode SomeMethod()
{

try
{
   var foo1 = SomeDataSource.Entities1.Single(x=> x.bar1 == somevalue);
}
catch(InvalidOperationException x)
{
   return ErrorCode1;
}

try
{
   var foo2 = SomeDataSource.Entities2.Single(x=> x.bar2 > somevalue);
}
catch(InvalidOperationException x)
{
   return ErrorCode2;
}

......
```

This is adding up to be a lot of try-catch blocks, as there are several error conditions that can potentially exist. It is also forcing me to elevate the scope of variables like `foo` to outside the individual try blocks, as they are being used in subsequent try blocks.

I am just curious to see if there is a way to consolidate all this code in a more elegant manner (some inline methods perhaps?) so that it doesn't end up looking so intimidating?

Based on the feed back I got, I have to add that the Business Rules that I am trying to implement leads me to use 'Single' and not 'SingleOrDefault'. Using 'SingleOrDefault' makes it easier because then we can just check for null without catching the exception. 'Single' on the other hand simply throws an exception if the condition fails. Idea here is to consolidate all these try blocks where as somehow keep all the errors happening separate even though every call to 'Single' throws the same type of exception (InvalidOperationException)...

Thanks

Comment: you can use the microsoft appliction error logging block

Comment: Do you have some subset of errors {n} that you're trying to map a larger set of all possible LINQ errors {m} onto?

Comment: @Micheal McPherson: yes

Comment: Could you clarify why you must call `Single()` instead of `SingleOrDefault()`?  Business requirements shouldn't specify that you call a particular method.  That's an implementation detail.  Business requirements specify that you need to implement specific behavior.  `SingleOrDefault()`is the most correct way to return an error code if there is no element that matches your condition.

Comment: @Dan The Business rule says that there must be 'one' and only one entity in the data store at a given time that satisfies the given condition. Think of a device with a given serial number in the list of devices. If that serial number is not there or there is two of them, then the rule fails and an error should be returned.

I thought the best way to achieve this is by calling 'Single'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move your business logic into the lambda method, which it sounds like, you can do so by defining an extension.

**Note: I am not endorsing the code below at all; I'm just trying to make it fit the question that you have asked.**

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static ErrorCode BusinessSingle(this IEnumerable<TSource> enumerable, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        TSource result;

        try
        {
            result = enumerable.Single(predicate);

            return new NoError(); // ????
        }
        catch
        {
            return new ErrorOne();
        }
    }

}
```

But it would be far better to do one of the following:

- If **errors are common**, then don't treat it like an `Exception` but rather a validation rule.
- If **errors are exceptional**, then throw `Exception` that are differentiated.

Answer (score 4):

You are misusing exceptions for control flow. Better:

```
var foo1 = SomeDataSource.Entities1.SingleOrDefault(x=> x.bar1 == somevalue);
if (foo1 == null) return ErrorCode1;
```

Very clean and simple.

What's especially vexing in the original code is that you are treating all occurrences of `InvalidOperationException` as the same thing. Who knows whether that's true or not?! There can be many things throwing this particular exception type. You might hide bugs by catching too generously. You might even hide EF bugs this way.

Comment: My apologies for not stating this in the original question. Business rules that I am trying to implement dictate that I must call 'Single' not 'SingleOrDefault'. Thus, there is no null return. It just throws an exception when a single entity that satisfies the given condition is not found.

Comment: That's not a business rule. Is it a technical rule imposed by your boss? Why?

Comment: The Business rule says that there must be 'one' and only one entity in the data store at a given time that satisfies the given condition. Think of a device with a given serial number in the list of devices. If that serial number is not there or there is two of them, then the rule fails and an error should be returned. I thought the best way to achieve this is by calling 'Single'

Comment: That is so not obvious the way you wrote it with Single. See how using exceptions for control flow obfuscates the problem? What about `.Take(2).Count() == 1`? You can make that into a reusable helper `HasExactlyOne()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that if you're always expecting exactly one element to match your condition, you should use `Single()` rather than `SingleOrDefault()`.

That means that if that is not the case, your system is a faulted state, and your application should shut down because it is not working correctly.  By saying `Single()`, you're saying "I know there's exactly one there. If there's not, there's something seriously wrong."

By trying to handle the exception and return an error code instead, you're saying something different.  You're saying "There should be exactly one there, but if there's not, I can do something else to handle that case."  That's what `SingleOrDefault()` is for.